# iPhone app not running on device after integrated Sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, sharekit

I had integrated ShareKit 2.0 in my iPhone application. After that I am not able to run it on a device. But there is no error while I run it on the simulator. The following error message shown in the console while running on the device.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/231C92DC-765F-47AA-BF5A-7A4AEF708C94/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /var/mobile/Applications/231C92DC-765F-47AA-BF5A-7A4AEF708C94/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this happens on older iOS < 5.1

There is [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/394) with fix on ShareKit github issue tracker, with hints. It will be fixed soon.

EDIT: fix has been merged to master. Please update.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I had updated the Sharekit and now it's fixed.